# Split first 10 characters of a string using CSPLIT

Tags: r

Is there a way to split specified number of characters from a given string using CSPLIT in R.

Ex: Table 1.1. Patient Completion Summary

Say for example I want to extract the table name (Table 1.1), I cant use a delimiter (.) here as I dont want to work on joining columns again.

I just want to extract first 9 characters.

Any ideas please.

Thank you

Comment: You can use `substr`/`substring` to get first 9 characters. Eg - `substr('Table 1.1. Patient Completion Summary', 1, 9)`. Do you always want to extract first 9 characters? Can you include first few rows of your data along with expected output? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sub` here for a base R option:

```r
input = "Table 1.1. Patient Completion Summary"
table_name <- sub("^.*\\b(Table \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*).*$", "\\1", input)
table_name

[1] "Table 1.1"
```

This answer is flexible and makes no assumptions about the table name, other than it be some number, followed by optional dot separator and digit, zero or more times over.